# How do I determine if MediaElement is playing?

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

Seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out any way to determine what the state of a MediaElement is. There are various properties for some states (such as IsBuffering) but I can't find any for states such as Play, Pause, etc. Silverlight seems to have a CurrentState property that shows all these.

Currently the way I'm determining whether a video is supposed to be playing is watching for various events and a timer that checks to see if any progress is being made.

I'm new to MediaElement and WPF (I'm actually only using MediaElement in a WinForms app). Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. You pretty much have to manually keep track of whether or not the media is playing. It's a pity, since it is so easy in Silverlight, as you mention. Seems like a major oversight to me.

Comment: I have added a feature request about this on the WPF GitHub repository. Please go give it a thumbs up. [Add CurrentState property to MediaElement #3655](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3655)

Answer (score 26):

You can get at the `_currentState` member using reflection.

```
    private MediaState GetMediaState(MediaElement myMedia)
    {
        FieldInfo hlp = typeof(MediaElement).GetField("_helper", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object helperObject = hlp.GetValue(myMedia);
        FieldInfo stateField = helperObject.GetType().GetField("_currentState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        MediaState state = (MediaState)stateField.GetValue(helperObject);
        return state;
    }
```

This covers play/pause, but doesn't change from 'play' to 'stop' when it finishes.

You can get around this by adding an event handler to the `MediaEnded` event, and running the `.Stop()` method, this changes the status correctly (which can be picked up by the method above)

Comment: Excellent solution! This is the way to do it.

Comment: unless Microsoft renames that field sometime in the future

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks. I see the potential danger in renames, but what other solution do we have? The `CurrentState` referenced below doesn't exist in modern full WPF.

Answer (score 9):

What I did to "work around" that was subclass MediaPlayer (this would work for MediaElement as well) and add my own methods to Play/Pause/Stop.  In those methods, I maintain a field which represents the playback status.  Also, you need to hook MediaEnded so that you can change the status from 'playing' to 'stopped.'

Comment: Put it up on CodePlex. If you don't have time, I plan to, just didn't want to step on any toes.

Answer (score 4):

For `Universal Windows 10 Platform (UWP)` :

```
if ( yourMediaElement.CurrentState.ToString() == "Playing" ) 
{
    //nou yourMediaElement is playng
}
```

or below if you wana use an `enum` instead:

```
if (yourMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
{
    //nou yourMediaElement is playng
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Silverlight` use CurrentState to check whether the state is playing or pause

```
 if (YourMediaElementName.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
 {
     // TODO: when media is playing.
 }
```

Comment: It should be noted that `CurrentState` is Silverlight only.

Answer (score 2):

And based on Rich S an extension can be implement

```
//don't forget
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Reflection;


 public static class Util
    {
     public static MediaState GetMediaState(this MediaElement myMedia)
        {
            FieldInfo hlp = typeof(MediaElement).GetField("_helper", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            object helperObject = hlp.GetValue(myMedia);
            FieldInfo stateField = helperObject.GetType().GetField("_currentState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            MediaState state = (MediaState)stateField.GetValue(helperObject);
            return state;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use MediaElement.CanPause it will determine if your currently playing media can be paused. Allows you to implement a Play/Pause button

```
var media = (MediaElement)obj;
  if (media.CanPause)
  {
    media.Pause();
  }
  else
  {
    media.Play();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

For the **WPF** MediaElement, here is the solution/workaround I use:

```
bool IsPlaying()
{
    var pos1 = wpfMediaElement.Position;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    var pos2 = wpfMediaElement.Position;

    return pos2 != pos1;
}
```

Comment: That's horrible workaround. If you call this method in UI thread, the whole UI will be forzen.

Comment: I agree, it is not the best methode. But I will bet no one on this world will recognize this one millisecond on small programs. Its an workaround from Alex wich I call quick 'n dirty and for that I will give upvote. Using a hidden HeperProperty by accessing hidden fields is really not a "nice solution" eigther.

Comment: nothing wrong with it.. media element not having status property is truly horrible solution... nobody asked you to call it in UI thread either.

Answer (score -1):

For WPF use this:
`var playing = player.Position < player.NaturalDuration;`