# Binding MediaElement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

We are trying to switch our application from code behind coding to MVVM pattern.

We have a MediaElement in our XAML file :

```
<MediaElement  Name="MyMedia" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"  MediaEnded="MediaEnd" MediaOpened="MediaBegin" Margin="10,24,13.6,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Visible" />
```

For the moment, with the code behind coding approach, we can access the MediaElement directly in the .xaml.cs file to call methods like `MediaElement.play()` or `MediaElement.pause()`.

The problem is that we are currently blocked when we try to convert our code to MVVM, because we can't access the MediaElement in the .cs file.
We are trying to bind the MediaElement itself so that we can call `play` or `pause` methods, but we haven't succeeded yet.

Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVVM pattern violation: MediaElement.Play()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631748/mvvm-pattern-violation-mediaelement-play)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the mediaelement in your viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

This link describes how to control it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx
it uses an event but still calls the MediaElement.play() in the event handler.

Comment: "Topic no longer available"