# Using MVVM, how can I establish a line of communication between a low level service and view model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I am implementing a media player app with Bluetooth connectivity using Prism and Unity.

The application flow I am working with goes as follows:

1. User issues a command on a remote device (phone/tablet)
2. Desktop application receives the `Play` command via a Bluetooth service
3. A higher level service processes the metadata and tells the `VideoPlaybackViewModel` to begin playing

### What I have so far

The Bluetooth service has not been implemented yet because I want to finish the other elements first. When it comes
time to do that, I will follow this example (https://github.com/saramgsilva/BluetoothSampleUsing32feet.Net).

Following this question ([MVVM pattern violation: MediaElement.Play()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631748/mvvm-pattern-violation-mediaelement-play)),
I have implemented `VideoPlaybackView` and `VideoPlaybackViewModel`.

`VideoPlaybackView`:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Views.VideoPlaybackView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:ia="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                 xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
                 prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
                 x:Name="MediaService">
        <ia:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ia:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MediaService}" />
            </ia:EventTrigger>
        </ia:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Grid>
            <MediaElement 
                x:Name="VideoPlayer"
                Source="{Binding VideoSource}" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

`VideoPlaybackViewModel`:

```
    public class VideoPlaybackViewModel : BindableBase {
        private Uri _videoSource;

        public IMediaService MediaService { get; private set; }

        public Uri VideoSource {
            get => _videoSource;
            set => SetProperty(ref _videoSource, value);
        }

        private DelegateCommand<IMediaService> _loadedCommand;

        public DelegateCommand<IMediaService> LoadedCommand {
            get {
                if (_loadedCommand == null) {
                    _loadedCommand =
                        new DelegateCommand<IMediaService>((mediaService) => { MediaService = mediaService; });
                }
                return _loadedCommand;
            }
        }
    }
```

These are initialized when the `VideoPlaybackModule` is loaded:

```
    public class VideoPlaybackModule : IModule {
        private IUnityContainer _container;
        private IRegionManager _regionManager;

        public VideoPlaybackModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager) {
            _container = container;
            _regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize() {
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(VideoPlaybackView));
        }
    }
```

I am using modules because I want to learn them.

### The goal

What I would like is to have a controller of some sort that can receive the events from the bluetooth service, 
parse the metadata, update the `MediaElement.Source`, and somehow send a command to the `VideoPlayerViewModel` 
to actually play the video.

### Attempts

I have seen the idea of implementing a controller, but I am not sure how I am supposed to initialize it. I come up
with the following questions:
 - How do I hook up the controller to respond to the Bluetooth commands from the Bluetooth service?
 - Should the controller keep a reference to `VideoPlaybackViewModel` in order to execute commands?

I think a service could be applicable here as well. If, for example, I created a `VideoPlaybackService`, how would this service be used? Similar to the controller idea, it would need to handle the processing of metadata before sending the command to `VideoPlayerViewModel`.

How can I use Prism and Unity to implement this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to do this, however it seems the *Mediator Pattern* might be the droids you are looking for. This will help reduce the *Coupling* your concerned about

[Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

> With the mediator pattern, communication between objects is
>   encapsulated within a mediator object. Objects no longer communicate
>   directly with each other, but instead communicate through the
>   mediator. This reduces the dependencies between communicating objects,
>   thereby reducing coupling.

[Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))

> In software engineering, coupling is the degree of interdependence
>   between software modules; a measure of how closely connected two
>   routines or modules are; the strength of the relationships between
>   modules.

In something like *MVVM Light* you could use the [MVVM Light Messenger](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger).

Its kind of like a [Pub/Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) affair, when you *Register/Subscribe* to a message, and your *Decoupled* class can *Publish/Send* said message.

However since you mentioned you are using *Prism*, you can use the [`EventAggregator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Once again this is a Pub/Sub arrangement.

[image]

**An example of sending an event from your Service**

```
this.eventAggregator  
    .GetEvent<PubSubEvent<BlueToothData>>()  
    .Publish(new BlueToothData { SomeData = someData });
```

**An example of receiving and event in your ViewModel**

```
var subscriptionToken = this.eventAggregator                             
                            .GetEvent<PubSubEvent<BlueToothData>>()                          
                            .Subscribe((details) =>  
                                   {       
                                       // what ever you want to do here;        
                                   });
```

***Note*** : I don't use Prism, however there are is a wealth of resources available for the EventAggregator

**Additional Resources**

[Prism Event Aggregator in WPF With MVVM](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/)

[Using the Event Aggregator Pattern to Communicate](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is the best approach given my problem. I wonder if this will still be OK to use as the complexity of the application grows. I'll save that thought for a later date.