# MediaElement doesn't show CurrentState

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mediaelement

So I've been trying to play a simple WAV file from my WinForms application. I've defined a MediaElement but when I try to get its current state, I can't see the CurrentState - does it has to do anything with ElementHost, UserControl etc.?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the WPF control called `MediaElement` in an `ElementHost` then I have to say that `MediaElement` doesn't have a property called `CurrentState`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx

You are probably mixing it up with the Silverlight one called the same:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(VS.95).aspx

This is a possible solution though:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819598/4620101